# Manifest error in Android

Tags: android

Currently i am working simple PayPal integration in Android, So i set the Manifest.xml file like

```
 <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity" 
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
           android:configChanges= "keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

But the error comes in SamplePaypal/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

How to fix this  issue, can u please help me

Thanks

Comment: You're missed to close the `configChanges` attribute with the `"` character.

Comment: Thanks for yur help, i already tried this scenario but no help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below manifest.xml code and see below link for more information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.paypal.MobilePayments.Pizza"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".PizzaMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[Integrate Paypal in Android Application](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-integrate-paypal-in-android.html)

Comment: Hi mr.Dipak, i have one doubt can we chat now

Comment: Hi Dipak
R u there?
I have one doubt in PayPal integration in Android?

Comment: STEP 1: Insert PayPal library in Build Path

Comment: Step 2: Then i set the manifest.xml file

Step 3: I have create one sample Button like Pay with Paypal, then i click the button

Comment: Dipak, now i send the project to your mail Id? no problem

Comment: I am new to Android development, so How to develop the Paypal integration in android

Answer (score 0):

replace `android:configChanges= "keyboardHidden|orientation/>`

with `android:configChanges= "keyboardHidden|orientation" />`

Comment: try closing the activity tag with with `>` instead of `/>` and then adding `</activity>` afterwards. clean the project, and build and run.

Comment: How to clean the project, any shortcut